# Error in Unix shell script by using oracle cursor

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, plsql

I keep on getting error as said below:

> line 10: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `')L_QUERY

My shell script code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash 
sqlplus -silent USERNAME/PASSWORD@DBS <<SQL_QUERY
begin
  for cur_r in (select Branch, Account_Type, Title, FirstName, LastName, Birthday, WorkPhone, HomePhone, Address, State, Zip, Email from accountrequest_temp)
  loop
    insert into accountrequest (Branch, Account_Type, Title, FirstName, LastName, Birthday, WorkPhone, HomePhone, Address, State, Zip, Email)
      values (cur_r.branch, cur_r.account_type, cur_r.title, cur_r.firstname, cur_r.lastname, to_date(cur_r.birthday, 'DD/MM/YYYY), cur_r.workphone, cur_r.homephone, cur_r.address, cur_r.state, cur_r.zip, cur_r.email);
  end loop;
end;
SQL_QUERY
```

Please help.

Comment: First, I should mention that this isn't a great use of a cursor.  You should instead use `INSERT INTO...SELECT`.  This will improve your performance by not making individual `INSERT` calls for each record and reducing the number of context switches.  If you did that, you wouldn't even need the `PL/SQL` block.

Comment: Here is a link to an Oracle article explaining my cursor comment in more detail: [Link](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/bulk-processing-with-bulk-collect-and-forall)

Comment: @Butter : From your error message, you see that your shell complains about an unterminated HERE-document. This means that `sqlplus` is not even invoked, which in turn means that, whatever error you may have in your SQL query, it has nothing to do with your problem. I can not reproduce the HERE-error, so either you have not pasted your command verbatim (I guess your username is not really `USERNAME`), or that you have some non-printable characters in your script. My feeling is that the latter is correct, so I would look at the script as a hex-dump to check for erroneous characters.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you have two errors:

- When you use a `BEGIN/END` block, you need to finish with `/`. If not, it is interpreted as a comment and it won't be executed.
- You are missing the end quote in the `TO_DATE` function

Besides the point that you don't need a cursor for this, it would be

```
#!/bin/bash 
sqlplus -silent USERNAME/PASSWORD@DBS <<SQL_QUERY
begin
  for cur_r in (select Branch, Account_Type, Title, FirstName, LastName, Birthday, WorkPhone, HomePhone, Address, State, Zip, Email from accountrequest_temp)
  loop
    insert into accountrequest (Branch, Account_Type, Title, FirstName, LastName, Birthday, WorkPhone, HomePhone, Address, State, Zip, Email)
      values (cur_r.branch, cur_r.account_type, cur_r.title, cur_r.firstname, cur_r.lastname, to_date(cur_r.birthday, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), cur_r.workphone, cur_r.homephone, cur_r.address, cur_r.state, cur_r.zip, cur_r.email);
  end loop;
commit;
end;
/
SQL_QUERY
```

Although I would do this instead

```
#!/bin/bash 
sqlplus -S USERNAME/PASSWORD@DBS <<SQL_QUERY
set echo off 
insert into accountrequest (Branch, Account_Type, Title, FirstName, LastName, Birthday, WorkPhone, HomePhone, Address, State, Zip, Email)
select Branch, Account_Type, Title, FirstName, LastName, to_date(birthday, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), WorkPhone, HomePhone, Address, State, Zip, Email from accountrequest_temp;
commit;
SQL_QUERY
```